# My search thorugh files seems to get indexerror

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

The error message I recieve is IndexError: tuple index out of range.
That's weird since I don't use tuple in this code, how should I fix it?

```
import os
import glob
import pathlib

lista = []
word = input("Write searchword: ")
file_path = input("Write pathway: ")
for path, directories, files in os.walk(file_path):
    count = 0
    if os.path.isdir(file_path):
        for p in pathlib.Path(file_path).glob("."):
            with open(p) as user:
                    for line in user:
                        if word in line:
                                count += 1
            if count > 0:
                new = str(p).split("'")
                lista.append(new)
                lista.append(count)
                lista.append("\n")
        name = ' '.join(str(w) for w in lista)
        print (name)
```

Comment: Please add the full traceback so we can see where the error is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

If you had read and posted the full Traceback then you would have seen that the `IndexError: tuple index out of range` is in `glob()`, not your code.

The error is in your `glob()`  construct, in that "." is not a usable pattern, I suggest:

```
for p in pathlib.Path(file_path).glob("./*"):
```

But I have to wonder if `glob()` is a good technique in this case.